# Problem with installing wine through "Ubuntu Software"

Tags: software-installation, wine

I was trying to install wine through the Ubuntu software as seen in the screenshot below:

[image: Click Here]

but got a error saying that it has unmet dependencies.

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on my desktop
with AMD Ryzen 5 (1600), 1050ti Nvidia graphics card

what should I do to resolve this problem?

Comment: Open a terminal and paste the output of `sudo apt install wine-stable`

Comment: didnt work as it said i have broken packages

Comment: Yeah that's what we need, details about the broken packages. Do post the output.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button or click the word in this comment to add the request information. Also please use {} to format it as code.